# I need help fixing an error message - "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol"

Tags: c++, class, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am having this error message whenever I tried to compile

```
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl MergeSort(class LinkedList<int> &)" (?MergeSort@@YAXAAV?$LinkedList@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\FOla Yinka\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\C++\linkedlist.obj    C++
Error   7   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\FOla Yinka\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\C++\Debug\C++.exe 1   1   C++
```

I have this in my header file

```
        template<typename T>
        class LinkedList{
              protected:

              public:
                 friend void MergeSort(LinkedList<T> &list);
        };

        template<typename T>
        void MergeSort(LinkedList<T> &list){

        }
```

To check if the fault is in the function declaration, I turned all the `protected` members `public` and I removed the friendship so `MergeSort` can have access to all memebers and then the program compiled successfully. I don't know why I am having this error message.

Comment: everything in the header file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to define the `friend` within the class body:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList{
      protected:

      public:
        friend void MergeSort(LinkedList<U> &list)
        {}
};
```

The other solution is to declare the `friend` before the class body so that it knows the `friend` is a `template`:

```
template <typename T> class LinkedList ;
template <typename T>  void MergeSort(LinkedList<T> &list) ;
```

and then in the class body declare the `friend` like this:

```
friend void MergeSort<>(LinkedList<T> &list) ;
```

This [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html) entry goes into the complete details of why you need a special work-around in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that once your class template is instantiated for (say) `T=int`, the `friend` declaration declares the existence of a *non-template* function:

```
 friend void MergeSort(LinkedList<int> &list);
```

In your code, this function does not exist. There is a function template called `MergeSort()`, but that is not the same thing you are declaring as a `friend`.