# Template class with a friend function which is inside a nested namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, friend

I'm trying to create a template class with a friend function which is inside a nested namespace. It works fine if I remove all the namespaces or if I remove all the templatization. But with both in place it won't compile. Let's look at some code:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    // Forward declaration
    template <typename Type>
    class Container;

    // Forward declaration
    namespace AccessPrivateImplementation
    {
        template <typename Type>
        Type getValue(Container<Type>* container);
    }

    // Templatized class
    template <typename Type>
    class Container
    {
        friend Type AccessPrivateImplementation::getValue(Container<Type>* volume);
    private:
        Type value;
    };

    // Friend function inside a namespace
    namespace AccessPrivateImplementation
    {
        template <typename Type>
        Type getValue(Container<Type>* container)
        {
            return container->value;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyNamespace::Container<int> cont;
    MyNamespace::AccessPrivateImplementation::getValue(&cont);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (VS2010) tells me:

> error C2248: 'MyNamespace::Container::value' : cannot access private member declared in class 'MyNamespace::Container'

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Try declaring `getValue` before `Container`.

Comment: This thread may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288446/i-need-help-fixing-an-error-message-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol/16288486#16288486

Comment: @Pubby - Thanks, but the getValue needs to come second because it takes a pointer to Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `friend` declaration inside the `Container` class template declares a friend **non-template** function `getValue()` that lives in the `AccessPrivateImplementation` namespace.

However, you haven't provided such a function. Instead, what you have in the `AccessPrivateImplementation` namespace is a function *template*, whose appropriate specialization you want to be `friend` of `Container<T>` (for a given `T`).

To achieve this, the declaration you need is:

```
friend Type AccessPrivateImplementation::getValue<>(Container<Type>* volume);
//                                               ^^
```

Here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/rIO9df) that shows your code compiling with the above fix.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sample code, but it doesn't actually fix it in my case (same error message). That website appears to use Clang so I'm wondering if it could be a VS2010 issue? I will try and work it out...

Comment: @DavidWilliams: It may be an issue with VC10, yes.

Comment: I think VS2010 is being a bit screwy here. As I mentioned, it compiles on VS2010 if I strip out the namespaces and this doesn't make sense given your explanation. This action doesn't help on Clang (which then fits with what you say). I think I'll just have to work around this but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, if you declare the `friend` like so it will work:

```
friend Type AccessPrivateImplementation::getValue<>(Container<Type>* volume);
                                                 ^^
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work (same error message)... but I want to believe you because the other answer says the same thing. I'm wondering if it is a VS2010 specific issue as the other answer provides code which appears to compile on Clang.

Comment: @DavidWilliams I don't have VS2010 but it would not be the first time VS had an issue, I would ask Andy if knows as well